# css grid alternate row color and put a box-shadow

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

Im using Grid to create a price table with a lot of informations, but i need to change some rows background colors and apply a box shadow. Im using react with styled components.

How can i change just some rows of my table? When a put background-color in my XML just the "lorem ipsun" background change, but the whole row dont. What i need to do?

OBS: that textHTML its a personal component that i use to make the style. Create this with style components ( width: ${p => p.width }; )

My grid table now:
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omoro.png)

What i want to do:

[my future table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/593Lc.png)

My CSS

```
export const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;

  grid-template-columns: 400px 180px 180px 180px;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 14px;

  grid-template-areas:
    'VZ SN SN SN'
    'IL PP PP PP'
    'IL II II II'
    'IL IC IC IC'
    'IL IC IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IC IC'
    'IL IX IX IC'
    'IL IX IX IC'
    'IL IX IX IC'
    'IL IX IX IC'
    'IL IX IX IC';

    height: 80vh;


`;
```

My REACT-XML

```
<Grid>
      
        <TextHTML font="700 18px Roboto" color="white">1</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 18px Roboto" color="var(--green)" margin="0 0 20px 0">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 18px Roboto" color="var(--green)" margin="0 0 20px 0">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 18px Roboto" color="var(--green)" margin="0 0 20px 0">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;" >lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">R$ 0,00</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">R$ 39,00</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">R$ 89,00</TextHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto" > <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum (Outbound)</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum (Inbound)</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>  
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>
        
        <TextHTML font="400 12px Roboto" color="var(--black)" custom="justify-self: left;">lorem ipsum</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <TextHTML font="700 12px Roboto">X</TextHTML>
        <IconStyleHTML color="var(--green)" width="10px" height="auto"> <Check /> </IconStyleHTML>

 
    
 
</Grid>
```

Comment: looks like a real table, why not use a real html table ? with a grid , you'll need to draw an average repeating-gradient or select a different bg color to children(cells) from a pattern made from  an  :nth-child(8n + x)  selector .

Comment: while waiting for a feedback about the grid choice, here is a possibility via nth-child and bg https://jsfiddle.net/zkj8agy7/

Comment: Well, to be real with you, i never used that method to create a table. I know that look strange. However, it was rare that I needed to create a table. Maybe i can try, but i really appreciate that nth-child one. Looks preety simple and beauty.
What you thing it is better? Remake the table or just adapt with taht nth-child?

Comment: Ok, i try to use that example in my project but dont worked. But im still trying

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyfdcx1o/54/
I just change the colors

Comment: What's better could be what you handle the best in the end , but this kind is much of datas and can be dispatch into a table `<table><thead><tr><th></th><th>col title</th><th>col title</th><th>col title</th><tr></thead><tbody><tr><th>row title</th><td></td>...<tr><tr><!-- the next 4 and so on --></tr></tbody></table>` . ;)